# PHP REGEX delete brackets and text in brackets

Tags: php, regex

Need to delete brackets and text in it. For now, it almsot working. Deletes all text starting from bracket. 
My code:

```
$lines = preg_replace("/\(([^\d]+)/", '',  $lines);
```

For example, text:

```
Some random words (word1 / word2 / word3) aaaa
```

Code deletes all text after brackets too,

```
Some random words
```

but what I need to do is (what it should look like):

```
Some random words aaaa
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/\([^()]*\)/
```

- `\(` - opening bracket
- `[^()]*` - as many characters as possible, which are not brackets
- `\)` - closing bracket

You can optionally remove one space at the end (`/\([^()]*\) ?/`) so that you wont have two spaces where the removal happened.

---

Note that this wont handle cases of nested brackets like:

```
foo (bar (baz) quiz)
```

To do that, you will have to be a little more creative:

```
(?<no_brackets>[^()]*){0}(?<balanced_brackets>\(\g<no_brackets>\)|\(\g<no_brackets>\g<balanced_brackets>\g<no_brackets>\))
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/iL1bR1/3)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an extra `\)` at the end of your expression. As is, your expression will start matching the moment it finds an open bracket and keep on going.

Comment: Removing one space to maintain spacing between words would help too.